# PHP download a file from s3 based on URL?

Tags: php, curl, mod-rewrite

I want so that a user on my website can type in the url 
www.example.com/m/directory/anyname.extension and it will load a file from Amazon S3.

For example: www.example.com/m/bob/index.php will load instead a file from s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/m/bob/index.php

How do I do this? PHP, cURL, mod_rewrite?

I'm terrible with mod_rewrite and I have little experience with cURL so some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a small file, you can start very easily with file_get_contents.

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/m/bob/index.php");
?>
```

The readfile function would be better in general (I've just used file_get_contents to start testing always).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

You can try this:

```
<?php
 readfile($url);
?>
```

Comment: You should make your URL absolute: `"https://s3.amazonaws.com..."` not just `"s3.amazonaws.com..."`